# mb_substr() returns a blank string UNLESS last two parameters are omitted

Tags: php, string

I am getting really weird results from `mb_substr()` that go against what the documentation describes as the expected behaviour: when I pass in the last two parameters, `mb_substr()` returns a blank string. If I omit the last two parameters completely, it returns the expected result. Is there something I am missing or something wrong with my syntax? **EDIT:** I am wondering if this could be happening due to a server setting, as this wasn't happening when I had my code on a local server using MAMP.

**Documentation:**

`mb_substr ( string $str, int $start, int $length, string $encoding )` should return the portion of **`str`** specified by the **`start`** and **`length`** parameters.

**`length`**
Maximum number of characters to use from str. **If omitted or NULL is passed, extract all characters to the end of the string.**

[View on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php)

---

**My code:**

`$mb2 = mb_substr('Hello I am a string', 6, NULL, 'UTF-8');
echo 'mb2: ' . $mb2;`

**Expected behavior:**

mb2:  I am a string

**Actual results:**

mb2:

---

**My modified code:**

`$mb2 = mb_substr('Hello I am a string', 6);
echo 'mb2: ' . $mb2;`

**Actual results:**

mb2: I am a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything depends on PHP version you use. I've just tested it on my localhost changing PHP versions.

For the following code:

```
<?php

$mb2 = mb_substr('Hello I am a string', 6, NULL, 'UTF-8');
echo 'mb2: ' . $mb2;
```

PHP **5.6** outputs: `mb2: I am a string`

PHP **5.5.11** outputs: `mb2: I am a string`

PHP **5.4.31** outputs: `mb2: I am a string`

PHP **5.3.29** outputs: `mb2:`

So it seems there was a bug in previous PHP versions or PHP documentation has changed and earlier there was another documentation for PHP.

And to create safe code (working also in PHP 5.3) you could use:

```
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
$mb2 = mb_substr('Hello I am a string', 6);
echo 'mb2: ' . $mb2;
```

This will give the same result in all PHP 5.3+ versions

**EDIT**

Looking at [PHP Changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) you can read:

> Allow passing null as a default value to mb_substr() and mb_strcut(). Patch by Alexander Moskaliov via GitHub PR #133.

as of **5.4.8** so from this version it should work fine

Comment: Thank you Marcin. This must be why my code was working on my local development environment as it uses the latest version of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct way to use it. As it says in the [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php#77515)s, passing as NULL makes it interpret it as 0.

```
$mb2 = mb_substr('Hello I am a string',6,mb_strlen('Hello I am a string'),'utf-8');
```

http://ideone.com/wYPYWM

Comment: For reference, see the [comment here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php#77515).

Comment: Thank you. I'll add that as a link within the answer :)

Comment: Thank you @AliGajani wish I could choose two answers, as I feel that Marcin gave the better explanation as to what was happening, but you actually provided me with the code that fixes the problem  since my server is stuck with PHP 5.3